# htop: show processes of all users except root

Tags: htop

I am aware of the `-u` option in htop, where I can show only processes of a given user, such as:

```
htop -u root
```

I am wondering whether there is a way to show processes of all user except root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, as of htop 0.8.3.

Source: the source code.

The best you can do is sort processes by user, root's processes will be conveniently lumped together.

Comment: And here is the [Github issue](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/94).

Comment: Is this possible with the latest `htop` version?

Comment: @alper I don't think so. The feature request was rejected and I can't see anything like that in the interface of htop 3.0.5, but I haven't checked the source code.